# ¿Cómo hacer un scrollView infinito en xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, scroll

Necesito hacer un scroll view infinito,pero no sé como. Este es mi codigo:

```
 string[] array1 = { "hotel", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b" };
         StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
             {Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Goldenrod,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,};
      Content = new ScrollView{VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,Content = stackLayout,};
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {foreach (var na in array1) {stackLayout.Children.Add
                           (new Button{
                            Text = na,
                            TextColor = Color.Gray, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Button)) }
                           ); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado:

Lo que tu necesitas es un ListView. Imagínate un StackLayout que "consume" items desde una colección/enumerable, y los apila verticalmente de acuerdo a una plantilla por cada item de la colección.

Es mucho más fácil usar XAML que hacer las vistas a mano, te sugiero hacer algo como lo siguiente:

- Crea un proyecto Forms en blanco
- Abre el MainPage y quita el Label por defecto, reemplazándolo por:

  ```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding array1}" BackgroundColor="Goldenrod">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
              <Button Text="{Binding}" TextColor="Gray" />
          </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  ```
- Reemplaza el contenido de la clase MainPage que está en el code-behind (lo que aparece en el archivo MainPage.xaml.cs) por esto:

  ```
  public string[] array1 { get; set; }

  public MainPage()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      array1 = new string[]{ "hotel", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b" };
      BindingContext = this;
  }
  ```